# Use a SIM card module (SIM808) with the less battery possible

Tags: arduino, batteries, battery-operated, gsm, sim900

I'm using a SIM808 module (on a [breakout card](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1RjXfLFXXXXbFXFXXq6xXFXXX2/Free-shipping-DHL-EMS-MINI-SIM808-CELLULAR-font-b-GSM-b-font--font-b-GPS.jpg)) and I want to send only 20 bytes every 6 hours (i.e. 120 bytes per day), containing GPS position and some very short other data.

So I think I'll probably have to use an Arduino. **In order to use the less battery-possible**, should I:

1. Have the Arduino running fulltime (with `sleep` most of the time), and GSM connected all the time
2. Have the Arduino running fulltime (with `sleep` most of the time), and GSM off most of the time, and GSM turned on only 1 minute every 6 hours
3. Have the Arduino + GSM completely off most of the time, and have a timer chip (what chip?) powering on the Arduino + GSM chip only 1 minute every 6 hours.
4. Another idea that would use even less battery?

Obviously 1. is not optimal at all. Would you use 2. or 3. (if so, how?)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way is to completely switch of both the Arduino and GSM ... Let them start up by a timer chip (a simple 555 should suffice if using a fixed time anyway)... than let the Arduino start up, initialize the GSM and after the send, switch down.

6 hours between every communication seems worthwhile to switch it off completely and take the startup of the Arduino and GSM as only advantage.

Comment: Can a 555 have a 2 minutes on (let's keep 2 minutes to be sure everything worked) then 6 hours off period? How to set this period with a 555?

Comment: A 555 is a thirsty beast - even a CMOS one is about 0.1mA, or 100x more than a small CPU like an MSP430 asleep on a 32kHz crstal. Maybe the Arduino's CPU has a similar low power sleep mode?

Comment: @BrianDrummond do you mean that the Arduino itself in sleep mode could be less thirsty than a 555?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it, but I have no experience with both 555 and Arduino's sleep mode

Comment: [This sounds too good to be true](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/128685/43434), what do you think? (measured 7.25 uA when in power down mode)

Comment: @Bash that might be very possible, but also you need something to wake it up.

Comment: The MSP430 sleeps at about 0.7uA (I measured 0.8) with the 32.768kHz clock running and its own built-in timer primed to wake it up every minute. The Atmega328 used in the Arduino aren't that far behind, I'd believe 7uA. Whether the Arduino supports this or loses a few mA in regulators etc I can't say, but it's a safe bet you can develop on Arduino and tweak your own Atmega to hit that low power - as he says, that was a bare CPU on a breadboard. The "something to wake it up" is again, its own timer.